# Php form not working but not getting any error messages

Tags: php, forms, email

i recentlly uploaded my website and am having trouble getting my form to work. can someone help me out. Before I was getting an HTTP 500 error, and I realized I had a type in my code, but since I fixed it, I'm not getting any error, however Im also not receiving any emails upon submitting my form. can someone let me know what I did wrong ?!

```js
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $mailFrom = $_POST['mail'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    
    $mailTo = "info@orbitwebdesign.ca";
    $headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;
    $txt = "You have recieved an e-mail from ".$name.".\n\n".$message;
    
    mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers);
    
    header("Location: contact.php?mailsend");
} 

?>
```

```html
 <section class="section-form" id="contact">
            <div class="row">
                <h2>BOOK A FREE CONSULTATION!</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <form method="POST" action="contact.php" class="contact-form">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your name" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                            <label for="mail">Email</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
                   
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                            <label>Message</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                            <label>&nbsp;</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                            <input class="input-btn" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </form>
                
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Try as first step to ad `var_dump` to `$_POST` at the beginning of your PHP to see if he run it - this will also enable you to examine the content of the post you sent

Comment: You didn't get errors because you're not checking for them. Enable error reporting.

Answer (score 1):

the email address is stored in `$_POST['email']`.
but, in your contact.php, row 5:

```
$mailFrom = $_POST['mail'];
```

Try replacing `$_POST['mail']` with `$_POST['email']`

Hope it helps.

ps
Also the label in your html code is for '**mail**' too instead for '**email**' like the input tag

Comment: Awesome! thanks so much.  Once someone submits the form, where should it be redirecting to? back to the home page? once I tried submitting it just took me to a blank page with the extension /contact.php. should my last line in my php doc be  header("Location: index.html?mailsend"

Comment: Yes, you sholud take back the user to the page where the submitted form was; I suggest to pass a get variable in order to display a success/error message depending if mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers) returned TRUE or FALSE.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes, the `mail` command is locked by the provider. You can try the following to get more information:

```
$success = mail('example@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);
if (!$success) {
    $errorMessage = error_get_last()['message'];
}
```

Taken from [here](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mail.php#121163)

Or use a dedicated class like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) or similar.